# Show OverlayView marker in street view

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I wanted to create custom "HTMLMarker" for google maps, but I just found out, it is **not** displaying in the street view. I have searched docs, but nothing is written there. (Googled: "show OverlayView marker in street view")

```
interface HTMLMarkerOptions {
    position: google.maps.LatLng | google.maps.LatLngLiteral;
    content: HTMLElement;
}

class HTMLMarker extends google.maps.OverlayView {
    private _element: HTMLElement;
    private _isAppended = false;

    private _position: google.maps.LatLng;

    constructor(options: HTMLMarkerOptions) {
        super();

        this._position = this._createLatLng(options.position)

        this._element = document.createElement('div');
        this._element.style.position = 'absolute';
        this._element.appendChild(options.content);
    }

    _appendDivToOverlay() {
        const panes = this.getPanes();
        panes.overlayMouseTarget.appendChild(this._element);
        this._isAppended = true;
    }

    _positionDiv() {
        const map = this.getMap();
        if (map instanceof google.maps.StreetViewPanorama) {
            //  TODO: Render in StreetView
            return;
        } else {
            const projection = this.getProjection();
            const point = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this._position);
            if (point) {
                this._element.style.left = `${point.x - this._offset.left}px`;
                this._element.style.top = `${point.y - this._offset.top}px`;
            }
        }

    }

    setMap(map: google.maps.Map | google.maps.StreetViewPanorama | null) {
        super.setMap(map);
    }

    draw() {
        if (!this._isAppended) {
            this._appendDivToOverlay();
        }
        this._positionDiv();
    }

    remove(): void {
        this._element.parentNode?.removeChild(this._element);
        this._isAppended = false;
    }

    setPosition(position: google.maps.LatLng | google.maps.LatLngLiteral): void {
        if (!this._LatLngEquals(this._position, position)) {
            this._position = this._createLatLng(position);
        }
    }

    getPosition(): google.maps.LatLng {
        return this._position;
    }

    getDraggable(): boolean {
        return false;
    }

    private _createLatLng(
        position: google.maps.LatLng | google.maps.LatLngLiteral,
    ): google.maps.LatLng {
        if (position instanceof google.maps.LatLng) {
            return position;
        } else {
            return new google.maps.LatLng(position);
        }
    }

    private _LatLngEquals(
        positionA: google.maps.LatLng | undefined,
        positionB: google.maps.LatLng | google.maps.LatLngLiteral,
    ): boolean {
        if (!positionA) {
            return false;
        }

        if (positionB instanceof google.maps.LatLng) {
            return positionA.equals(positionB);
        } else {
            return positionA.lat() == positionB.lat && positionA.lng() == positionB.lng;
        }
    }
}
```

[example fiddle (compiled TS to ESNext)](https://jsfiddle.net/z5r9hm2y/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had a look at this yesterday and as mentioned by geocodezip, the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview#StreetViewOverlays) is misleading (or wrong). It mentions that

> *if you explicitly set the map's streetView property to a StreetViewPanorama of your own construction, you will override the default panorama and disable automatic overlay sharing*

which to me would mean that if you are **not** using a *panorama of your own construction* (and therefore the **default** panorama), overlay sharing should work, unless if by *"overlay"* they meant *Marker*.

Here is a proof that a standard `Marker` is shared between the map and the default panorama without the need to do anything and the custom overlay isn't:

```js
var map;
var panorama;
var htmlMarker;

function initialize() {

  function HTMLMarker(lat, lng) {
    this.lat = lat;
    this.lng = lng;
    this.pos = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    this.divReference = null;
  }

  HTMLMarker.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

  HTMLMarker.prototype.onRemove = function() {
    this.divReference.parentNode.removeChild(this.divReference);
    this.divReference = null;
  }

  HTMLMarker.prototype.onAdd = function() {

    div = document.createElement('DIV');
    div.className = "html-marker";
    div.style.width = '60px';
    div.style.height = '50px';
    div.innerHTML = 'ABC';

    var panes = this.getPanes();
    panes.overlayMouseTarget.appendChild(div);

    this.divReference = div;
  }

  HTMLMarker.prototype.draw = function() {

    var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();
    var position = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.pos);
    var panes = this.getPanes();

    panes.overlayMouseTarget.style.left = position.x - 30 + 'px';
    panes.overlayMouseTarget.style.top = position.y - 25 + 'px';
  }

  // Set up the map
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.729884, -73.990988),
    zoom: 18,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    streetViewControl: false
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  panorama = map.getStreetView();
  panorama.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(40.729884, -73.990988));
  panorama.setPov({
    heading: 330,
    zoom: 1,
    pitch: 0
  });

  htmlMarker = new HTMLMarker(40.729952, -73.991056);
  htmlMarker.setMap(map);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(40.729952, -73.991198),
    map: map,
    draggable: true,
    title: 'My marker'
  });
}

function toggleStreetView() {
  var toggle = panorama.getVisible();
  if (toggle == false) {
    panorama.setVisible(true);
  } else {
    panorama.setVisible(false);
  }
}

var button = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
button.onclick = function() {
  toggleStreetView()
};
```

```css
#map-canvas {
  height: 150px;
}

input {
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 4px 8px;
}

.html-marker {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Toggle Street View">
<div id="map-canvas"></div>

<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initialize" async defer></script>
```

And here, when changing from map to default panorama, I simply do

```
htmlMarker.setMap(null);
htmlMarker.setMap(panorama);
```

and it works.

```js
var map;
var panorama;
var htmlMarker;

function initialize() {

  function HTMLMarker(lat, lng) {
    this.lat = lat;
    this.lng = lng;
    this.pos = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    this.divReference = null;
  }

  HTMLMarker.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

  HTMLMarker.prototype.onRemove = function() {
    this.divReference.parentNode.removeChild(this.divReference);
    this.divReference = null;
  }

  HTMLMarker.prototype.onAdd = function() {

    div = document.createElement('DIV');
    div.className = "html-marker";
    div.style.width = '60px';
    div.style.height = '50px';
    div.innerHTML = 'ABC';

    var panes = this.getPanes();
    panes.overlayMouseTarget.appendChild(div);

    this.divReference = div;
  }

  HTMLMarker.prototype.draw = function() {

    var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();
    var position = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.pos);
    var panes = this.getPanes();

    panes.overlayMouseTarget.style.left = position.x - 30 + 'px';
    panes.overlayMouseTarget.style.top = position.y - 25 + 'px';
  }

  // Set up the map
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.729884, -73.990988),
    zoom: 18,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    streetViewControl: false
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  panorama = map.getStreetView();
  panorama.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(40.729884, -73.990988));
  panorama.setPov({
    heading: 330,
    zoom: 1,
    pitch: 0
  });

  htmlMarker = new HTMLMarker(40.729952, -73.991056);
  htmlMarker.setMap(map);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(40.729952, -73.991198),
    map: map,
    draggable: true,
    title: 'My marker'
  });
}

function toggleStreetView() {
  var toggle = panorama.getVisible();
  if (toggle == false) {
    panorama.setVisible(true);
    htmlMarker.setMap(null);
    htmlMarker.setMap(panorama);
  } else {
    panorama.setVisible(false);
    htmlMarker.setMap(null);
    htmlMarker.setMap(map);
  }
}

var button = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
button.onclick = function() {
  toggleStreetView()
};
```

```css
#map-canvas {
  height: 150px;
}

input {
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 4px 8px;
}

.html-marker {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Toggle Street View">
<div id="map-canvas"></div>

<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initialize" async defer></script>
```

I have opened [a new issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/159575621) in the tracker. Let's see if this is a bug in the API, or an issue with the documentation (or both).

- Fiddle showing how to do it: http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/mLa4zvs7/
- Fiddle showing that overlay sharing does **not** work by default: http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/xsqvm6n0/

Comment: Good job... though there seems to be a bug :D If you change fov (scroll wheel in Streetview) and exit Streetview the marker will disappear!
As it seems, this will require quite a bit of work. I will probably look into creating npm package to solve all problems (toggle between map/streetview, scaling when far in ST, hide when very far in ST, and (sadly) other)

Comment: Scaling based on the distance would be a feature request. I do not see the bug you mentioned with the marker disappearing (Chrome browser on Mac).

Comment: You can star the [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/159575621) in the tracker to get notified if/when the issue is updated.

Comment: I was exiting Streetview via the button it provides, instead of the green one you made...

Answer (score 2):

Although [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview#StreetViewOverlays) says:

> Additionally, when creating a map with a default StreetViewPanorama, any markers created on a map are shared automatically with the map's associated Street View panorama, provided that panorama is visible.

That doesn't seem to be true for the `HTMLMarker`.  Setting the `map` property of the `HTMLMarker` to the default Street View panorama of the map:

```
marker.setMap(map.getStreetView());
```

makes it visible.

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/2dv9t0yo/2/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

Related question: [Drawing polylines on Google Maps Streetview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31646669/drawing-polylines-on-google-maps-streetview)

**code snippet:**

```js
const map = new google.maps.Map(
  document.querySelector('#map-canvas'), {
    zoom: 18,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.422, -122.084),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  },
);
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
  console.log(e.latLng.toUrlValue(6));
})
class HTMLMarker extends google.maps.OverlayView {
  constructor(options) {
    super();
    this._isAppended = false;
    this._position = this._createLatLng(options.position);
    this._element = document.createElement('div');
    this._element.style.position = 'absolute';
    this._element.appendChild(options.content);
  }
  _appendDivToOverlay() {
    const panes = this.getPanes();
    panes.overlayMouseTarget.appendChild(this._element);
    this._isAppended = true;
  }
  _positionDiv() {
    const map = this.getMap();
    const projection = this.getProjection();
    const point = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this._position);
    if (point) {
      this._element.style.left = point.x + 'px';
      this._element.style.top = point.y + 'px';
    }

  }
  setMap(map) {
    super.setMap(map);
  }
  draw() {
    if (!this._isAppended) {
      this._appendDivToOverlay();
    }
    this._positionDiv();
  }
  remove() {
    if (this._element.parentNode) {
      this._element.parentNode.removeChild(this._element);
    }
    this._isAppended = false;
  }
  setPosition(position) {
    if (!this._LatLngEquals(this._position, position)) {
      this._position = this._createLatLng(position);
    }
  }
  getPosition() {
    return this._position;
  }
  getDraggable() {
    return false;
  }
  _createLatLng(position) {
    if (position instanceof google.maps.LatLng) {
      return position;
    } else {
      return new google.maps.LatLng(position);
    }
  }
  _LatLngEquals(positionA, positionB) {
    if (!positionA) {
      return false;
    }
    if (positionB instanceof google.maps.LatLng) {
      return positionA.equals(positionB);
    } else {
      return positionA.lat() == positionB.lat && positionA.lng() == positionB.lng;
    }
  }
}

const marker = new HTMLMarker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(37.42197, -122.083627),
  content: document.querySelector('#marker'),
});
marker.setMap(map);

const marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(37.42197, -122.083627),
});
marker1.setMap(map);
// We get the map's default panorama and set up some defaults.
// Note that we don't yet set it visible.
panorama = map.getStreetView();
panorama.setPosition({
  lat: 37.421885,
  lng: -122.083662
});
panorama.setPov( /** @type {google.maps.StreetViewPov} */ ({
  heading: 0,
  pitch: 0
}));
panorama.setVisible(true);
panorama.setZoom(1);
marker.setMap(map.getStreetView());
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

#map-canvas {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: #CCC;
}

#marker {
  display: flex;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: white;
  border: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>

<div id="map-canvas"></div>

<div id="marker">
  ID: 1
</div>
```

Comment: So I need to listen to the `visible_changed` event on `google.maps.StreetViewPanorama` and change the map back and forth... It is a solution, yet it is not nice... I guess a tradeoff for working at a low level... And I need to hide the marker in Streetview if too far, as well as scale it down...